# Xcode not adding framework when pushing on github

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, git

So I am trying to push and swift application on github and I am facing some problems.

I've included a Framework called 'chats.ios' on my project. ( I've added the framework using the build phases page and add ir to and the framework manually on link binary with libraries. ). In my computer it is working just fine.
But when I pushed my project on GitHub and one pull it from another MAC, it seems to miss the library. I've added manually also, but when I am trying to build the project, all references of the framework are not found. And I think that when I try to put it on the store, the framework won't go aswell. Any ideias of what could be wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is where you added the framework under a .ignore path in your .ignore file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please make sure that your "chats.ios" library is under git root path or sub path
- Please check your .gitignore file if you sure it is in your git path by the command:

`tail .gitignore`

You may add frameworks and linked them appropriately even though they are not inside your project directory. However, git will only upload files inside it. In other words, xcode care the dependency, while git only care absolute paths.

Regarding your last concern, as long as you can compile the project on your computer properly, it will be archived correctly for submitting on App Store (I suppose your "on the store" means App Store).